# Deployed application doesn't work after changes connectionString MVC ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, oracle, entity-framework

I made application using DataBase First approach with oracle (in this way https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tk_EDjTzZCE so I used Entity Wizard)

I deployed my application on http://www.smarterasp.net/ 
Everything works fine.

But I decided to change `connectionString` in webconfig. Because I wanted to use database from another server. New Database has literaly same structure as old but still doesn't work.

Also I tried to change `connectionString` before deploy. I compiled the application and when I run - receives an error: `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`
[image]

If I add database again using Entity Wizard (check youtube link above) then everything works fine. How can avoid this? Maybe my `connectionString` is wrong?

```
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="DbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DAL.DbModel.csdl|res://*/DAL.DbModel.ssdl|res://*/DAL.DbModel.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=some-link.com:1521/ORCLBK;PASSWORD=some_password;USER ID=some_login&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Is the database dns public? Try using the database IP number instead

Comment: It doesn't matter because as i said. If I will add connection database using Entity Wizard, then works fine

Comment: When you add the connection to the database using Entity Wizard, aren't you doing that on your local computer through VS thats keept in a different domain then smarterasp.net?

Comment: The error is: `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` so connection is correct.